# replacing a ground wire with a neutral

Tags: wiring

Have a three prong outlet schematic that shows two hots and ground. The appliance has a three prong 40 plug. The appliance case has a separate ground terminal. Can I replace the outlet ground with a neutral wire and use that ground to ground the appliance at it's ground terminal?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the receptacle's junction box? Also, is it fed from the main panel or a subpanel?

Comment: Does this outlet need to be able to switch between this new appliance (??) and whatever's plugged in there now?  What is it?

Comment: I recently purchased a plasma torch that runs on 240v/(40a max) or on 120v/20A. The unit's cord has a two blade/one rounded plug. The unit also came with a pig tail with a recepticle for that plug and a standard 120V plug. The unit automatically senses  the difference and acts accordingly. Although the barn has 240 supplied to it, there is not a 240 plug available for this unit where I need it. I would like to make an extension cord of sorts, but prefer to have four wire instead of three. The unit has an exterior ground terminal. Coming from the main cb panel to a 40A four wire easy for me.

Comment: Getting from the units three wire to the four wire outlet is my challenge. I have a Leviton three wire 50A rated outlet for one end of my extension cord. Problem is the schematic for it shows hot/hot/ground. What I prefer is to have that plug hot/hot/neutral so the actual ground is connected to the plasma unit's ground terminal. The panel in the barn is a sub and does have the ground separate from neutral and they both feed back to the house main. In effect the extension cord would now have hot/hot/neutral supplying the unit's plug and the true ground used at the unit's ground terminal.

Comment: I understand your concern but it may be a non issue. Since the plasma cutter automatically senses the voltage it probably has a universal voltage power supply and the unit itself may be isolated. I would contact the manufacturer or read the owners manual to verify.

Comment: I checked that pigtail. Continuity between the 120 ground and the 240 (ground?/neutral?), continuity between the 120 neutral and the 240 large spade (similar to a 120 large spade, larger than the hot...), and continuity between the 120 hot and the 240 smaller spade (similar to a 120 small spade, smaller than the neutral).

Comment: I agree with you, Ed Beal. It may well be a non-issue. This pigtail check is telling me the unit has a lot of 'sense' to it. Two things I want to avoid: lousing up a nice, new plasma torch and...lousing up an old guy. Would aggravate the missus. I am a fan of stuff being properly grounded. I also checked for continuity between the unit's 240 ground/neutral plug pin and that ground terminal on the back of the unit case. There is none. I would like to use that.

Comment: By the way....I really appreciate all the help I'm receiving with this issue. Thank you very, very much.